Creating a Custom List in SPFx
I'm new to SPFx and my goal is to create a custom list. I've looked up various documentations and guides and videos but its still not getting the result i want. Not to mention most of the reference material for it is pretty outdated.
First I ran the SharePoint Yeoman Generator and selected the no framework option. Then I created the elements.xml and scheme.xml under sharepoint > assets folder.
I updated/added elements.xml, schema.xml and package-solution.json files and these are given below.
elements.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

    <Field ID="{E97812C0-C488-469D-B049-B1F44185A373}" Name="SPFxNameOfContractor" DisplayName="Name of Contractor" Type="Text" Required="TRUE" Group="Contingent" />

    <Field ID="{3E4805B6-A01B-469E-B1C8-133D85839B7D}" Name="SPFxWorkRegion" DisplayName="Work Region" Type="Choice" Required="FALSE" Group="Contingent">
        <CHOICES>
        <CHOICE>North America</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Europe</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Asia</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
    </Field>

    <Field ID="{BF94FCF6-49F5-4387-A03F-D450AB79D07B}" Name="SPFxWorkCountry" DisplayName="Work Country" Type="Choice" Required="FALSE" Group="Contingent">
        <CHOICES>
        <CHOICE>USA</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>UK</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Germany</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Japan</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>India</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Malaysia</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
    </Field>

    <Field ID="{20F73BED-5C48-455D-9EE1-9443805475D4}" Name="SPFxWorkLocation" DisplayName="Work Location" Type="Choice" Required="FALSE" Group="Contingent">
        <CHOICES>
        <CHOICE>Texas</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Berlin</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Tokyo</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Pune</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Mumbai</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
    </Field>

    <Field ID="{67F4DC6D-F229-4E6E-884A-C35369F40265}" Name="SPFxSupplier" DisplayName="Supplier" Type="Choice" Required="FALSE" Group="Contingent">
        <CHOICES>
        <CHOICE>Supplier 1</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Supplier 2</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Supplier 3</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
    </Field>

    <Field ID="{68615B47-8A0F-474B-A442-243F3C3974BA}" Name="SPFxPONumber" DisplayName="PO Number" Type="Text" Required="TRUE" Group="Contingent" />

    <Field ID="{2AA23336-A2CA-48A0-8C86-E049DB045A64}" Name="SPFxJobFamilyOrGroup" DisplayName="Job Family or Group" Type="Choice" Required="FALSE" Group="Contingent">
        <CHOICES>
        <CHOICE>Job Family 1</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Job Family 2</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Job Family 3</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
    </Field>

    <Field ID="{F65DA85E-CEA9-4656-9F50-908F1F7E6B02}" Name="SPFxInvestmentResources" DisplayName="Investment Resources" Type="Boolean" Required="FALSE" Group="Contingent" />

    <Field ID="{23F41D89-9DA4-402C-B5D9-4FA1B007A866}" Name="SPFxResourceType" DisplayName="Resource Type" Type="Choice" Required="FALSE" Group="Contingent">
        <CHOICES>
        <CHOICE>Project Based</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Outcome Based</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>T and M</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Investment</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
    </Field>

    <Field ID="{9FA26EF2-2C45-45CD-B64D-D63AF2228CBF}" Name="SPFxIsPersonWorkingStill" DisplayName="Is this person working Still?" Type="Boolean" Required="FALSE" Group="Contingent" />

    <Field ID="{26AFAB2E-28A5-46BB-85A5-FBF408E2DD0C}" Name="SPFxStatus" DisplayName="Status" Type="Choice" Required="FALSE" Group="Contingent">
        <CHOICES>
        <CHOICE>Pending</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Completed</CHOICE>
        </CHOICES>
    </Field> 

    <ContentType ID="0x0100828B198FB17B4C4BBF9071EB478FC30B" Name="ContingentContentType" Group="ContingentContentTypes" Description="This is Content Type for Contingent">
        <FieldRefs>
            <FieldRef ID="{E97812C0-C488-469D-B049-B1F44185A373}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{3E4805B6-A01B-469E-B1C8-133D85839B7D}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{BF94FCF6-49F5-4387-A03F-D450AB79D07B}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{20F73BED-5C48-455D-9EE1-9443805475D4}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{67F4DC6D-F229-4E6E-884A-C35369F40265}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{68615B47-8A0F-474B-A442-243F3C3974BA}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{2AA23336-A2CA-48A0-8C86-E049DB045A64}"/>
            <FieldRef ID="{F65DA85E-CEA9-4656-9F50-908F1F7E6B02}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{23F41D89-9DA4-402C-B5D9-4FA1B007A866}"/>
            <FieldRef ID="{9FA26EF2-2C45-45CD-B64D-D63AF2228CBF}" />
            <FieldRef ID="{26AFAB2E-28A5-46BB-85A5-FBF408E2DD0C}" />
        </FieldRefs>
    </ContentType>

    <ListInstance CustomSchema="schema.xml" FeatureId="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100" Title="Contingent" TemplateType="100" Description="Contingent Information List created using Sharepoint Framework" Url="Lists/Contingent">
    </ListInstance>

</Elements>

schema.xml:
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Contingent Information List" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/ContingentInformation" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
        <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0100828B198FB17B4C4BBF9071EB478FC30B"/>
    <ContentTypes>

    <Fields></Fields>

    <Views>
        <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouhttps://devofficecdn.azureedge.net/sharepointdocumentation/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
            <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
            <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
            <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
            <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
            <ViewFields>
                <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>
                <FieldRef Name="SPFxNameOfContractor"></FieldRef>
                <FieldRef Name="SPFxWorkRegion"></FieldRef>
                <FieldRef Name="SPFxWorkCountry"></FieldRef>
                <FieldRef Name="SPFxWorkLocation"></FieldRef>
                <FieldRef Name="SPFxSupplier"></FieldRef>
                <FieldRef Name="SPFxPONumber"></FieldRef>
                <FieldRef Name="SPFxJobFamilyOrGroup"></FieldRef>
                <FieldRef Name="PFxInvestmentResources"></FieldRef>
                <FieldRef Name="SSPFxResourceType"></FieldRef>
                <FieldRef Name="SPFxIsPersonWorkingStill"></FieldRef>
                <FieldRef Name="SPFxStatus"></FieldRef>
            </ViewFields>
            <Query>
                <OrderBy>
                    <FieldRef Name="ID" />
                </OrderBy>
            </Query>
        </View>
    </Views>

    <Forms>
        <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
        <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
        <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>

package-solution.json:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json",
  "solution": {
    "name": "spfx-list-for-contingent-information",
    "id": "543b9fc7-f58f-48f9-bcc2-964b29c0bd1e",
    "version": "1.0.0.0",
    "includeClientSideAssets": true,
    "isDomainIsolated": false,
    "features": [{
      "title": "spfx-list-for-contingent-information",
      "description": "asset-deployment-webpart-client-side-solution",
      "id": "2E5BD71D-34B2-4223-8277-DF576ED9F08F",   
      "version": "1.0.0.0",
      "assets": {
        "elementManifests": [
          "elements.xml"
        ],
        "elementFiles":[
          "schema.xml"
        ]
      }
    }]
  },
  "paths": {
    "zippedPackage": "solution/list-for-contingent-information.sppkg"
  }
}

After this I ran:
gulp clean
gulp build
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship

After this, I uploaded the .sppkg file to my tenant and was deployed without any errors but the new created list was not showing. I believe the main cause of the issue I'm facing has to something with the code in the package-solution.json file.
Few other details = Node version - v18.17.1, npm version - 10.4.0, Typescript version 4.7.4.

Is this a web part solution? You have to add the web part on specific SharePoint site so that list asset will be created on that site.

Hi Ganesh, yes it is a webpart solution. Can you be a bit more specific on what to do here?

Where exactly you want to create this list, on app catalog site or on the site where you will be adding your web part?

Check this for deploying and using your web part on site: Deploy your client-side web part to a SharePoint page. Let me know if it works for you.

You need to set "skipFeatureDeployment" to false in package-solution.json file.
